# DbContext & Auto mapper - An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

This is helper which i used for initializing the Automapper :

```
public interface IAutoMapperConfig
    {
        MapperConfiguration CreateMapperConfig<T>() where T : Profile, new();
    }

public class AutoMapperConfig :IAutoMapperConfig
{
    public  MapperConfiguration CreateMapperConfig<T>() where T : Profile, new()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new T());
        });
        return config;
    }
}
```

And i called helper method in one of my Repository and passing mapping profile to CreateMapperConfig.

```
    public class ClosedOrderRepository : IclosedOrders
    {
        private readonly OrdersContext _ordersContext;
        private readonly IAutoMapperConfig _autoMapperConfig;

        public ClosedOrderRepository(OrdersContext orderContext, IAutoMapperConfig autoMapperConfig)
        {
            _autoMapperConfig = autoMapperConfig;
            _ordersContext = orderContext;

        }

    public List<ClosedOrdersDTO> SalesInvoiceOrders() //thrown exception here 
    {
        var config = _autoMapperConfig.CreateMapperConfig<ClosedOrderProfile>();

        var SalesInvoiceOrdersDB= _ordersContext.SalesLine
                .Where(f => f.Type == 2)
                .ProjectTo<ClosedOrdersDTO>(config)
                .Take(100)
                .ToList();
        return SalesInvoiceOrdersDB;
    }

}
```

Here is mapping profile. As you can see, some of the mappings are using the `DbContext`, so I have to somehow inject it in the ClosedOrderProfile

```
public class ClosedOrderProfile : Profile
{
    private readonly OrdersContext _ordersContext;
    public ClosedOrderProfile(OrdersContext orderContext)
    {
        _ordersContext = orderContext;

    }
    public ClosedOrderProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Sales_Invoice_Line, ClosedOrdersDTO>()
        .ForMember(r => r.NumberofItems, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quantity))
        .ForMember(r => r.SerialNumber, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => _ordersContext.item_Ledger_Entries
                    .Where(serial=>serial.Entry_No_ == src.Value_Entry.Item_Ledger_Entry_No_)
                    .Select(no=>no.Serial_No_).ToList()));
    }

}
```

Here is Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           services.AddScoped<IAutoMapperConfig, AutoMapperConfig>();
           services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
        }
```

But, When i run the code i will get this error :

> An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query
> parameter expression. To show additional information call
> EnableSensitiveDataLogging() when overriding DbContext.

Can anyone please help me or point me into the right direction :)
Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid that I might not completely understand the flow of the code, but aren't you just missing Dependency Injection for the OrdersContext?

Comment: I just updated the question :)

Comment: I assume this error occurs because when you are using `_autoMapperConfig.CreateMapperConfig<ClosedOrderProfile>()` the parameterless constuctor is used and therefore `_ordersContext ` is not set. But appart from that passing a `DbContext` into AutoMapper is really bad design and should be avoided at any cost. Automapper should just be responsible for mapping but nothing else - especially potentially asynchronous operations like retrieving data from the database. Your repository sould be responsible for loading all the data needed and then pass it to AutoMapper.